# Some streams terminated before this command could finish! Structured Streaming : com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException

Tags: python, spark-streaming, azure-databricks

I'm working on a code in databricks which is consuming data from eventhub and pushing the data to ADLS Gen2 after flattening.
On executing the code I'm getting **com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException** error.
Not sure why getting this error instead of using proper connection string that too in encrypt format.

**Spark Version** - *3.0.1*

**Scala Version** - *2.12*

**Maven Library** - *com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.21*

**JARS Used** -
*dbfs:/FileStore/jars/8c706747_a660_4cf5_802a_f58ba54e30cb-azure_eventhubs_1_0_1-1879e.jar
dbfs:/FileStore/jars/a894f1b6_fe5e_4d5c_b98b_1406ce3aef10-azure_eventhubs_spark_2_11_2_3_1-ac355.jar
dbfs:/FileStore/jars/3f483534_fbc7_47aa_a415_39305e18c10b-proton_j_0_25_0-70af2.jar
dbfs:/FileStore/jars/744788e8_65d3_4e43_952f_ec8fc7578b58-slf4j_api_1_7_25-784af.jar*

**Error Message:**

*java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: status-code: 401, status-description: Generic:
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.liftedTree1$1(EventHubsClient.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCountLazyVal$lzycompute(EventHubsClient.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCountLazyVal(EventHubsClient.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCount(EventHubsClient.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.partitionCount(EventHubsSource.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.$anonfun$maxOffsetsPerTrigger$4(EventHubsSource.scala:96)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.$anonfun$maxOffsetsPerTrigger$2(EventHubsSource.scala:96)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.<init>(EventHubsSource.scala:96)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: status-code: 401, status-description: Generic:
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.amqpResponseCodeToException(ExceptionUtil.java:90)
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageOperationResult.onComplete(MessageOperationResult.java:32)
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageOperationResult.onComplete(MessageOperationResult.java:10)
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.RequestResponseChannel$ResponseHandler.onReceiveComplete(RequestResponseChannel.java:254)
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ReceiveLinkHandler.onDelivery(ReceiveLinkHandler.java:122)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:185)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
at com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:784)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: status-code: 401, status-description: Generic:
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.liftedTree1$1(EventHubsClient.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCountLazyVal$lzycompute(EventHubsClient.scala:184)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCountLazyVal(EventHubsClient.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.EventHubsClient.partitionCount(EventHubsClient.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.partitionCount(EventHubsSource.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.$anonfun$maxOffsetsPerTrigger$4(EventHubsSource.scala:96)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.$anonfun$maxOffsetsPerTrigger$2(EventHubsSource.scala:96)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource.<init>(EventHubsSource.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider.createSource(EventHubsSourceProvider.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:93)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(MicroBatchExecution.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$1(TreeNode.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDown$3(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:430)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:252)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:428)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:375)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDown$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:313)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(MicroBatchExecution.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.logicalPlan(MicroBatchExecution.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:346)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:269)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.AuthorizationFailedException: status-code: 401, status-description: Generic:
Thanks is advance for any inputs on the above issue.**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your **connection string**, please follow below code:

```
connectionString = "YOUR.CONNECTION.STRING"
Conf = {}

Conf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```

Check this [**document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/databricks-stream-from-eventhubs) and [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69656402/how-to-ingest-data-from-eventhub-to-adls-using-databricks-clusterscala) by Alex Ott

Comment: As per your suggestion I have changed the code from 

        connectionstring = connection_string        
        ehConf = {}
        ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionstring)
 
     to      

        connectionstring = connection_string        
        Conf = {}
        Conf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionstring)
and now getting below error

_Exception: org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt does not exist in the JVM_

Comment: Hi @Anikesh Paul, please follow this related [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63479113/some-streams-terminated-before-this-command-could-finish-structured-streaming) thread  and  this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkNmb5Ij8mY&t=4s) it will solve your problem.